# String.Equals() not working as intended

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, equals

I am using LINQ to search through one of my Entity Framework tables and find a "group" based on the name. The name is a string and appears to be Unicode (says it is in the edmx). I have a method `GetGroup()` and I pass in a name to search for. Debugging through the code, I already have a group named "Test" in my database. Once I pass in a group named "TEST" I expect it to return the "Test" which was already in the database. It for some reason, does not find the "Test" and thinks "TEST" doesn't exist. Here is my query, I cannot see why it does not work. Please help.

"name" is the passed in the group name. My `.Equals` seems to only work if the `gr.Name` and name are the exact same. If one character is capital in one of the two strings, then the .Equals doesn't work.  I have tried to use `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, and that did not seem to help.  In case someone asks, the `MyLeagueId` and `LeagueId` will always match, the database is setup so there can be a group in a different league id. I do not think this is the problem.

```
Group g = (from gr in this.DatabaseConnection.Groups
           where gr.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
           gr.LeagueId == this.MyLeagueId
           select gr).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Are you sure one doesn't have a space at the end/beginning that the other one doesn't have?

Comment: If the Groups table is not too big, then as a test, can you try changing the query to ... from fr in this.DatabaseConnection.Groups.ToList() ...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When using LINQ to Entities, it will automatically convert it to LINQ to SQL. And if the database field you are doing a .Equals on does not have a collate of NOCASE (SQLite in my example) then it will always be case-sensitive. In otherwords, the database defines how to do the string comparison rather than code.

Comment: So is there a way to perform a case insensitive search with LINQ to Entities?

Comment: Just have the DB field contain the NOCASE for the collate (for SQLite, not sure on other DBs. Im sure its similar).

Comment: I just tested `str1 == str2` and it does a case insensitive search, so I don't need the `Equals` hassle. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 48):

The string comparison with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` works in memory or with `IEnumerable<T>`. You are trying to use it with `IQueryable<T>`, but the provider of your queryable does not understand it.

This works for me:

```
db.Users.FirstOrDefault(
     s => s.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
);
```

Comment: static method `string.Equals` did not worked, even with the same arguments. Using instance method was solution.

Comment: I wonder why I get "Method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL."?

Answer (score 14):

Use the `String.Compare()` as it can be translated to Sql.

[Here](http://blogs.telerik.com/openaccessteam/posts/12-04-17/string-matching-in-linq.aspx) are some examples of string matching in Linq, with the Sql translation as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Mainly for the awesome **String Matching in LINQ** link, that explains it so clearly.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work in Oracle's ODP.NET as the SQL still translates to normal comparison.

Comment: This doesn't work in MS SQL Server, again query is client evaluated. I checked by setting ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)) in OnConfiguring method.

This provides some good solutions-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity

In my case, my DB fields were Case-insensitive, so equality operator == worked fine.

You can check your DB fields using-
https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-check-case-sensitivity-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 10):

Made some research. You can't do. The collation (the type of comparison) is defined at the column level of the table. You can't modify it through EF. If it's defined as case insensitive, then all the searches will be case-insensitive. If it's defined as case sensitive, then your only hope is `ToUpper()` the strings.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/435783/entity-framework-conceptual-model-doesnt-support-string-equals-via-linq

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3810aa67-f6fe-4624-a14b-eaaa0e05ddcd

[EF4 Linq Oracle11g making queries none case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763182/ef4-linq-oracle11g-making-queries-none-case-sensitive)

[LINQ to Entities case sensitive comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

Comment: Didnt work. I get this exception (not sure why...both my objects I am comparing are strings): Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.StringComparer'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: @Travyguy9 Changed suggestion :-)

Comment: String.Equals gives me this error (StackTrace ends in LINQ, so LINQ doesn't like it I assume) - Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'

Comment: ToUpper/ToLower work...which I find stupid..Shouldn't using IgnoreCase for my StringComparison do this for me?

Comment: You are without hope :-) In the end you'll have to ToUpper() both strings (I've read that it's better than ToLower). If you stay away from Turkish and some other languages you shouldn't have problem.

Comment: @Travyguy9 In the CurrentCulture, have you used the form str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)?

Comment: No, ToUpper and ToLower are totally different beasts. There are some problems with some letters. The lower case ı (it's a turkish character) when converted in upper case is equal to I (that is the upper case of european-american i). And there are probably tons of these examples.

Comment: Yea I have tried all 3 StringComparison's with IgnoreCase. All failed.

Comment: @Travygui9 I'll add another link. Still no good news :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Answer (score 6):

I like TravyGuy's answer from a technical perspective.
For a more direct, practical answer, try using:

```
string.Compare(string A, string B, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `name.Equals(gr.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

If it works then the problem could be with `gr.Name`.

--- Edit ---

I'm guessing that `gr.Name` is not of type `System.string`. (since `String.Equals` gives you an error ==> from the previous post)

give this a shot

```
(gr.Name as string).Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

or

```
String.Equals((gr.Name as string), name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```