# LINQ case sensitive

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

How to make LINQ case sensitive and NOT case sensitive depending on the situation?

I'm using sql server 2008 and Entity Framework 4.0.

I changed the COLLATION to make SQL Server case sensitive. so that for scenarios like these:

```
 query = query.Where(x => x.Username == username);
```

it works great.
However I need to be able to pull out data from db **ignoring case** when searching by subject (or name or similar) like so:

```
query = query.Where(x => (x.Name.Contains(Name)));
```

which doesn't work when record is "TestString" and i'm looking for "test" or "Test" or similar. How would i make it so that when it would find a text or part of a string in a text?
thanks

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Comment: Use the ToUpper/Lower solution or write a SQL query like this instead:`SELECT * FROM tblUser
WHERE tblUser.userName = 'test' COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

LINQ has no concept of case sensitivity, it only cares about boolean evaluation. So if you want to ignore case, you should do something like:

```
query = query.Where(x => (x.Name.ToLower().Contains(Name.ToLower())));
```

Chances are you will want to pass a `CultureInfo` to ToLower() (or use `ToLowerInvariant()`), and you might want to cache the result of `Name.ToLower()` so as to not have to perform that operation a potentially large number of times, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 8):

```
query = query.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 2):

Read my reply to this:

[String.Equals() not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080727/string-equals-not-working-as-intended/5081892#5081892)

It isn't the reply you wanted, probably :-)

Ah... and if you have to convert to the same case to make comparisons, ToUpper is better than ToLower. Don't ask me why. But you can read here: [Case insensitive string compare in LINQ-to-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841226/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 2):

`Queryable.Contains` has an overload taking an `IEqualityComparer<T>` used for comparision. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341422.aspx). If you supply a case insensitive comparer, this should work - I'm quite sure there is one in the framework already.

Comment: I think IEqualityComparer<T> is only supported in Linq to objects