# Case insensitive query using EF6 and Npgsql

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I am using EF 6 + npgsql. I am trying to run a query that checks if a user with a given name (case insensitive) exists in db. I tried:

```
context.Users.Any(u => u.Name.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

however it doesn't work. Any help ?

Comment: [linq case sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104520/linq-case-sensitive)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help me much. I need a way to run a "case insensitive query" on postgresql database using EF.

Comment: `var name = (username ?? string.Empty).ToLower(); var any = context.Users.Any(u => u.Name.ToLower() == name);`

Comment: Yeah, but this is a workaround. I am looking for an option built into EF/Npgsql.

Comment: No, there is no such built-in option. EF follows the default database collation setting. You can try request it [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic). If you want to apply the case sensitive globally, you need to change the collation in the database level, something like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Or [intercept the query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) to add `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` query in the where clause (but this will be overkill).