# Entity Framework and Case Insensitive String Search

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a Entity Framework entity with a string Property named Description.
Searching for all entities where the Description contains a string is as simple as:

```
var res = from u ctx.Users where u.Description.contains(str) select u;
```

But suppose I want to support case insensitive search?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to entities case sensitive comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

Comment: You can use the ToUpper() as I have written here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080727/string-equals-not-working-as-intended/5081892#5081892

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using `Linq to enties` the search is done by the sql server so if the search is case sensitive or not depends on server settings.

Comment: And what about Oracle. If the dataAccess is built on top of EF because of Multi-RDBMS support. I can't resolve the problem on Oracle.

Comment: So there is no way to specify whether we want a case sensitive or case insensitive search using EF?