# Entity Framework - case insensitive Contains?

Tags: entity-framework

I want a solution to this problem that does not involve ToUpper or ToLower, as I use in the code below;

```
var upper = term.ToUpper();
using (var db = this.DataContext)
{
    return db.Counties.Where(x => x.CountyName.ToUpper().Contains(upper)).ToList();
}
```

I am using entitly framework so the C# solution of using `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` does not work. It does work for `Equals`, `EndsWith` and `StartsWith`, but not `Contains`.

Comment: Perhaps this answer is one you can employ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/3312

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Contains Case Insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive) or [Case insensitive contains(string)] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Neither of them apply. Those solutions do not work in entity framework as I tried to point out in the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: Sorry bout that. How's about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3843382/3312 ? It's the reverse, but the solution is the same - change the collation on the column in the database.

Comment: I think you are wrong to close this question as an exact duplicate. I appreciate that it may look like it is, but the solutions do not work in Entity Framework, that was why I asked it.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this?

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question as it asks about Entity Framework  specifically. The implementation of `String.Contains` is different for different providers, for example Linq2Sql is always case insensitive.

Comment: Have you considered using Dynamic Linq for this? See http://blog.falafel.com/implement-case-insensitive-string-comparisons-with-dynamic-linq/ for more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework and Case Insensitive String Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415267/entity-framework-and-case-insensitive-string-search)

Answer (score 9):

I know that this is not related directly to EF, but only solution I can think of is to alter DB table column collation to be Case Insensitive e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ALTER COLUMN COLUMNNAME nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
```

CI - case insensitive /
CS - case sensitive

AS - accent sensitive /
AI - accent insensitive (can also be useful)

If you can't change collation of table column you can use direct query from EF with forcing collation

```
select * 
from table
where country collate Latin1_General_CI_AS != @country
```

Answer (score 7):

I use EF6 and Sql Server and `Contains` is mapped to `LIKE '%@p0%'` which is case insensitive in my case. So in my case:

```
db.Counties.Where(x => x.CountyName.Contains(term)).ToList();
```

works as needed. More info in [Sjoerd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965710/1718832).

Comment: In your case means only that you have configured Case Insensitive DB collation. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: In my case, I can run your query and it is case sensitive. So I think @Tomas has it figured, But would be awesome if EF could add a feature to specify. Cause one could want case sensitive in 1 query and then case insensitive in another.

Comment: misleading answer

Answer (score 2):

Just add `.ToLower()` from `upper`

```
 using (var db = this.DataContext)
            {
                return db.Counties
                       .Where(x => x
                       .CountyName.ToLower()
                       .Contains(upper.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: If you read the question I point out that I do not want to use that as the answer.

Comment: Right now this is the only answer I can seem to find?

Comment: This answer helped me haha ... I just switched to using lower instead of upper .. thanks mate!