# Use contains with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase function c#

Tags: c#, contains, string-comparison

I'm trying to populate all the results that contains the letters provided by the user.

```
foreach (var item in entries.PhonebookList.Where(ab => ab.FirstName.Contains(fName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Record: {0}  {1}  {2} ", item.ItemNumber, item.FirstName, item.LastName);
}
```

But I'm getting an error inside the `Contains` method.

> "No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments"

What is the best way to use `Contains` with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` method?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `fName` - `string`?

Comment: Are you sure that you want `Contains` but `Equals`?

Comment: Yes I need Contains. For example I have Sheng and Sheldon as firstnames. When I use Equals and I provide "she" as parameter for fName. it will not display Sheng and Sheldon since it did not meet the required value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) you should use `string.IndexOf(string, StringComparison)` instead.

So basically its:

```
    var entries = new 
    {
      PhonebookList = new[]
      {
        new { ItemNumber = 1, FirstName = "Leonard", LastName = "Hofstadter" }, 
        new { ItemNumber = 2, FirstName = "Sheldon", LastName = "Cooper" }, 
        new { ItemNumber = 3, FirstName = "Howard", LastName = "Wolowitz" }, 
        new { ItemNumber = 4, FirstName = "Sheng", LastName = "?" }, 
      }
    };
    
    var fName = "she";
    foreach (var item in entries.PhonebookList.Where(ab => ab.FirstName.IndexOf(fName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Record: {0} {1} {2}", item.ItemNumber, item.FirstName, item.LastName);
    }
```

Which returns:

> Record: 2 Sheldon Cooper
>
> Record: 4 Sheng ?

If you often need a `Contains` with a different `StringComparison` the documentation also provides an extension method you can implement, to use it like `Contains` (see the given example in the provided link).

Comment: I didn't get any error. I got the same result. if I use "she" as parameter for fName variable. It didnt display the expected result. I have Sheng and Sheldon in my for firstname.

Comment: See my updated example. I suppose you should double-check if your FirstName fields really contain the names you think they contain.

Comment: Yup I did. This is what I've observed. I have the following firstnames

Breth
Dioren
Klarence
Rey

If the parameter of my fName is "re". These names will display. However if i use "RE". They wont be displayed.

Comment: I checked it with your new examples. And it works for me regardless of the search terms casing.

What is the type of PhonebookList? Is it from an EntityFramework / NHibernate /ORM mapper query, i.e. of type IQueryable<...>? If yes, you may need to alter your DB table schema (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400856/entity-framework-case-insensitive-contains).

Comment: public List<PhonebookItem> PhonebookList { get; set; }

Comment: Then it should work. Did you check that your search text doesn't contain whitespace? E.g. if your fName is "RE" is fName.Length == 2?

Comment: @anonymousRey Apparently this is a correct answer in the context of LINQ to Objects and general C#.  If you claim it doesn't work (while it should), consider providing [mcve] to prove your claims, otherwise I would consider them being incorrect.

Comment: Sorry Ckuri. my bad on my side. there was a variable before my foreach that handles if the parameter being provided has corresponding result on my list. I modified it and its now working. Your answer now works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String.IndexOf` method instead of `Contains`. If you are interested in the position of the sub string value in the current instance, you can call the `IndexOf` method to get the starting position of its first occurrence, or you can call the `LastIndexOf` method to get the starting position of its last occurrence. `IndexOf(String)` method is used if a sub string is found in a string instance. Also you can use other overloads of `String.IndexOf` based on your purpose like the one with `String` and `StringComparison` arguments.