# How to ignore case for string comparison in DB2 (CurrentCultureIgnoreCase not working)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, db2

The CurrentCultureIgnoreCase operative worked fine on the SQL Server instance. It however isn't working on the DB2 instance I have of the same application.

I have tried the following ones:

Working (although concerned about performance hit):

```
s.POSTCODE.Trim().ToLower() == q.Trim().ToLower();
```

Not Working:

```
s.POSTCODE.Trim().Equals(q, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Not Working:

```
s.POSTCODE.Trim().Equals(q, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: In the first example you trim **q** too. StringComparison.*IgnoreCase does not perform any trimming.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that! I guess that works too, as well as my answer!

Comment: you should take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxc48dt hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the only string comparison denomination that works on DB2 is:

```
s.POSTCODE.Trim().ToLower() == q.Trim().ToLower();
```

Have tried various alternate forms with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Equals()`

So: `string.Equals(s.POSTCODE.Trim(), q.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Get the following error: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'

Comment: Using: var res = from s in db.ADDRESS
                          where string.Equals(s.POSTCODE.Trim(), q.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                          select s;

Comment: Ahh you're using it like that, I dont believe that is possible, maybe try Linq? `var res = dbContext.Address.Where(x=> string.Equals(x.POSTCODE.Trim(), q.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));`

Comment: hmm.. maybe see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080727/string-equals-not-working-as-intended But I just tried the code I posted in my comment and it worked fine :S

Comment: I on the main post that all the comparison attempts are working fine on the SQL Server database, but not on the IBM DB2 database. Think it's a bug. :S