# string.equals function not working correctly c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I am stuck in a very simple problem, I am just comparing two strings in c# inside an LINQ query's where clause. But it's not working on case sensitivity. I am tired.
Here's my code

```
public class User
{
    [Key()]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Fname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string Lname { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Ph_Num { get; set; }

    public string CNIC { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Username")]

    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Designation { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

and my cs code look like

```
public ActionResult Index(string username, string password)
    {
        if (username != "" && password != "")
        {
            //checking is user already exists

            //Here problem arise...

            var query = db.Users.Where(i => i.Username.Equals(username)).ToList();
            User res = null;
            if(query.Count == 1)
            {
                res = query.First();
            }
            if (res != null)
            {
                //My remaining code
            }
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: What does this mean: *"it's not working on case sensitivity"*?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But it's not working on case sensitivity"? Do you want to campare it case insensitive or case sensitive?

Comment: I don't know enough about LINQ to SQL to know what happens to your "where" lambda, but here's how to do case insensitive compares in pure C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371150/comparing-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-c-sharp

Comment: Note that `string.Equals(string)` will do a case sensitive comaparison in C#.  However this is being turned into SQL as it looks like you are using either EF or Linq-to-SQL.  That means the determination of whether the comparison is case sensitive or not is based on your DB and it's settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.Equals() not working as intended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080727/string-equals-not-working-as-intended)

Comment: If your DB settings are case insensitive and you want case sensitive you can do a second filter in Linq-to-Objects `db.Users.Where(i => i.Username == username).AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Username == username).ToList()`.  That will at least filter most things out on the DB side before doing the case sensitive in your code.

Comment: I want to compare case sensitive words. For example file and File should not be equal

Comment: juharr thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing 2 string values inside a LINQ lamda expression, It does a case sensitive comparison by default. But if you do not wish to have this behaviour, you can use a different overload of `Equals` method which takes a comparison type enum as the second argument, and you can  pass the type of comparison you want (Case sensitive or Case Insensitive). For case insensitive comparisons you may pass `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`

```
var resultsWithCaseIgnored = someEntityList.Where(i => i.Name
                      .Equals("scott",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

**But when you do a LINQ to SQL statement where it is going to generate a SQL statement and executes it, the generated SQL will be same for both the overloads.**

The case sensitivity of where clauses in your SQL statements depends on the collation settings you have on your db server / your db / your specific column.

You can verify your current setting by executing a sql statement like

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));
```

When i ran this in my sql server, the result i got was **`"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"`**. The `CI` part indicates, it is case insensitive. That means when i do `where UserName='scott'` and `where UserName='SCOTT'`, both will give me same result.

If you want to do a case sensitive check, there are ways to update your collation to be one which is case sensitive. But updating your db is not always a safe thing ( *think about the implications*)

What you can do is, query your db table, get the results to your C# objects then do a where clause ( ***which will be case sensitive***).

```
var users= db.Users.Where(i => i.Username.Equals(username)).ToList();

// do a case sensitive check on users
var user = users.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Username.Equals(username));
if(user!=null)
{
  // user has the User object
}
else
{ 
  // no user matching our CASE SENSITIVE UserName check.
}
```

Comment: Will EF or Linq-To-Sql actually work with that overload of `Equals`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shyju but I dont want to ignore case sensitivity. I want to to compare case sensitivity. As mentioned in question and also in comment.

Comment: @juharr It will not crash. But actually it generates the same SQL statement for both overloads. So it does not really matter. Your comment made me to learn something new today (SQL collations). Thank you.

Comment: @AdnanInayat See the updated answer for the possible root cause and a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NOT in C# ... the problem it's in your SGBD. For example, in SQL Server check what culture settings you have. If it is something containing "CI"  then everything will be compared in insensitive way. That's because what you see it's just an expression tree that is translated into plain SQL and executed ON your SGBD. More details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx

Note: you can trick this by calling "ToUpper" or "ToLower" in your LINQ query:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username, string password)
    {
        if (username != "" && password != "")
        {
            //checking is user already exists

            //Here problem arise...
            userName = userName.ToUpperInvariant ();
            var query = db.Users.Where(i => i.Username.ToUpper ().Equals(username)).ToList();
            User res = null;
            if(query.Count == 1)
            {
                res = query.First();
            }
            if (res != null)
            {
                //My remaining code
            }
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

This will be translated in SQL into something like UPPER (UserName) = 'BLABLA'

Comment: If the settings are insensitive there's no point to using `ToUpper` if the setting are case sensitive then you need to do the `ToUpper` on the variable and the column to get insensitive comparison.  The only way to get case sensitive filtering when the DB is insensitive is to do the filtering in Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: I think that more or less i said the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Linq query is being translated to SQL and thus the settings in your DB will determine if the comparison is case sensitive or case insensitive.  Since you want case sensitive, but are getting case insensitive I would suggest doing a second filter in Linq-to-Objects by using `AsEnumerable`

```
var query = db.Users.Where(i => i.Username == username)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(i => i.Username == username)
                    .ToList();
```

Basically this will ensure that the second `Where` will be executed in your code versus being translated to SQL.  And since string comparison in C# is case sensitive you should get what you want.  Note you would still want to keep the first `Where` to ensure that you don't return all the rows of the table from the DB which could be costly.  You'll just return rows that match in a case insensitive manner which will include any case sensitive matches as well.